# How to setup AWS cloudfront with https to EC2 http pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I have a EC2 instance which is running a simple react webapp behind an nginx (on port 80). I can access the app via through EC2 instances public IP.

But as it is "http", I want to make this pipeline move to https.

So I created a cloudfront rotation and associated an aws ssl cert with it. I have route 53 config which forwards traffic for one of my domain to this rotation.

Now I want to forward this traffic from cloudfront rotation to EC2 instance. I am not able to do this plumbing. I think it is because CF is on https and EC2 doesnt have a ssl enabled server. Is there a way I can work it out?

Please let me know if you would need me to post any screen shot from aws configs to see what I have configured.

Thanks a lot for your help on this matter.

## Updates on request

### Error i get says something like this (on browser)

```
This site doesnt support https
```

Some context on setup

### EC2 instance working on port 80 via curl

[image]

### Cloudfront rotation configuration  allowing only https from client

[image]

### Cloud front rotation configured to forward traffic to port ec2 at port 80 http

[image]

Comment: "I am not able to do this plumbing." Show what you have tried, and what specifically does not work (specific error messages, etc). CloudFront absolutely lets you send traffic to a non-secure origin server, so your thought about http being the problem is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkB added some details

Comment: Are you sure the URL you are entering in your web browser is a URL that points to CloudFront, not a URL that points to the EC2 instance?